# Ruby on Rails: Can't insert content into yield block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a partial called `_main_nav.html.erb` in views/layout folder, this is content file:

```
<% content_for :main_navigation do %>
  <h1>Something must here</h1>
<% end %>
```

In my `_header.html.erb` file, i used `yield` to insert content:

```
... 
<%= yield :main_navigation %>  
<nav id="utility" class="nav-collapse">
...
```

But when i visit home page, it does'n appear h1 element, i have wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to yield content from a view that isn't currently being rendered.

You would need to do:

**_header.html.erb**

```
... 
<%= render "layouts/main_nav" %>
<%= yield :main_navigation %>  
<nav id="utility" class="nav-collapse">
...
```

**_main_nav.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :main_navigation do %>
  <h1>Something must here</h1>
<% end %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: I saw guide in Rails View book, maybe they missed render layout. Thanks so much.